# When does cuneiform numbering "carry over"?

Tags: transliteration, cuneiform, sumerian

In theory, cuneiform glyphs are numbered to distinguish homophones: if there are two common glyphs pronounced `/u/`, one will be named *U₁* and the other will be named *U₂*. If a glyph has multiple readings, the number is attached to a particular reading, so the glyph *BI₁* is also known as *PE₂*, *PI₂*, *BE₂*, and *SA₁₈*, among others.

So far so good. But sometimes, the numbering seems to carry over from one reading to another. For example, the glyph *GU₁₀* can also be read as `/ŋu/`, and there are no other common glyphs with that reading. But its alternate name is *ŊU₁₀*, not **ŊU₁*—in fact, the name **ŊU₁* doesn't seem to be associated with anything at all.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34498/how-are-cuneiform-glyphs-numbered

Comment: "The name ... doesn't seem to be associated with anything at all", well, with the character itself, isn't it? I mean the way we call *P* by the name "Pe" or that squiggly a-character in Greek by the name "alpha" that doesn't mean *aleph* "bullseye" or anything really.

Comment: @vectory No, what I'm saying is that the name *_ŊU₁_ is not associated with any cuneiform character (hence the star). Which is strange, because 1 is supposed to be assigned before 2, 2 before 3, etc.

Comment: Maybe it's the way we call *P* by the name "Pe" or  "Rho" depending on codepoint. I still say alpha although it's clearly an A written in a funny hand. And even writing *alexander* in Latin codepoint--I'm more pragmatic than hardcore philologists at that---I might refer to it as alpha depending on the context. So in my mind Alpha1 is A2 and vice versa. Seems an orderly and forward compatible notation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any authoritative source backing this up, but as best I can tell from perusing the ePSD: **the numbering "carries over" from a reading using only Akkadian phonemes to a reading that contains non-Akkadian ones** (particularly Sumerian ĝ/ŋ and ř/dr). Akkadian has always been the best-understood of the languages using syllabic cuneiform, and tends to set the standards for naming.

I speculate that this stems from a combination of uncertainty in the readings (since the phonetic transcriptions we have were written by Akkadian-speakers) and from typographical concerns (ĝ, ŋ, and ř aren't always easy to typeset). But if anyone can find a Sumerological source that actually explains this rationale, I'd gladly take that as the accepted answer.